# Rachel and Peter Russo - do they remember each other?

Tags: house-of-cards

In *House of Cards* season 1,

Episode 1.  Peter Russo starts on his downward path when he gets arrested for drink-driving in his SUV with Rachel, whom you see really briefly.

Episode 10.  Doug has recruited/forced Rachel into a honeypot situation at a fundraiser to compromise Peter.  When Peter sees her, he is at first wary of giving up his sobriety and drinking with her (with good reasons as it turns out) and she spins him a story that she works there and has keys to the hotel.  To my recollection (I alternate between Netflix and Crave and am off Netflix right now), Peter does not seem to recognize her or mention her profession, otherwise he'd probably think it a really bad idea for a politician to fraternize in public with a call girl.

Why did Doug specifically recruit her, knowing that she had a history with Peter and that he could expect a good chance of Peter recognizing her and sensing either a trap or a potential for embarrassment?  And, no, gambling on the idea that Peter was too drunk in his SUV during episode 1 to recognize her would be risky.  Rachel was available, yes, but she could have been coerced into any other use, just not one involving tricking Peter.

Comment: While i have no definitive answer, my opinion was that he used Rachel because he already had contact to here and paid her money and he knew that Peter would be attracted to her. But all in all thats just speculation on my side